# Grouping time-series data by time intervals

Tags: timezone

Let's say we are storing data for 1000s of devices that collect a single type of data every 10s. Each device can be located in a different timezone. The ability to query quickly to visualize the data is important. We can ask the system questions such as the following:

```
1. For a specific device, I want the last 7 days of data grouped by day totals for my local timezone.
2. For a specific device, I want the last year's data grouped by month totals for my local timezone.
```

Storing all the data in UTC seems like the cleanest approach, however it becomes tricky when asking for local groupings of the data. For example, a day grouping for each timezone has different offsets. So if we were to store in say day, month, year "buckets" they would all be grouped relative to UTC which would not be useful for asking questions for timezones other than UTC itself.

If we were to group the data in minute and hour "buckets" (ignoring timezones that are off by less than an hour, e.g. IST +5:30) we could use the hour "buckets" to construct the answers to the above questions. For question 2, there would be 12 groupings of up to 744 hour "buckets" for each grouping.

Does the approach with minute and hour (ignoring timezones that are off by less than an hour, e.g. IST +5:30) "buckets" seem like a decent design? Has anyone designed something similar with a different suggestion?

Comment: How are you planning to use this data? Within an application? SQL queries & reports? OLAP cube?

Comment: @Peter Within an application. Assuming frequent lookup of the data.

Comment: Related reading: [Falsehoods programmers believe about time](https://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time)

Comment: I would recommend just storing the full timestamp data (with timezone) and then querying it using the appropriate operators.  [Postgres, at least](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html), has excellent operators and functions for working with timestamps, dates, and the like.